# Tcl Dev Kit: can't find package starkit

Tags: tcl, centos, starkit, tcldevkit

I am not able to wrap the most simple TCL application using [TclDevKit5.2](http://www.activestate.com/tcl-dev-kit/downloads).

I on 64 bit CentOS, and here wat `uname -a` returns:

```
Linux hp1 2.6.18-194.11.1.el5 #1 SMP Tue Aug 10 19:05:06 EDT 2010 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

When typing:

```
/opt/TclDevKit-5.2/bin/tclapp -out wrap empty.tcl
```

(here empty.tcl is an empty file) it generates the `./wrap` executable, however when trying to run `./wrap`, it reports this:

```
can't find package starkit
    while executing
"package require starkit"
    (file "./wrap" line 5)
```

Here are the first lines of `./wrap`:

```
#!/bin/sh
# \
exec tclsh "$0" ${1+"$@"}
##
package require starkit
starkit::header mk4 -readonly
##
# here goes the binary executable ....
```

What am i doing wrong? Where the `starkit` package is located? Maybe I have to add something to the `add_path`?

I am using the 21 days trial version of TclDevKit, and here is the log it reported while generating `./wrap`:

```
info      | Tcl Dev Kit TclApp
info      | Copyright (C) 2001-2010 ActiveState Software Inc. All rights reserved.
info      | Licensed to Trial User (Trial license, serial number *6928738*).
info      |
info      | Embedding license information into wrap result as comments.
info      |
info      | Expires: 18-11-2010.
info      | 
info      | WARNING:  All applications generated by this trial version
info      |           will also stop working on 18-11-2010.
info      Expanding...
info          Following only profile dependencies
info       
info      Issues...
info       
notice    Packages ...
notice    * No packages
info      Inserting "tclsh" into starkit header.
info      Inserting "-readonly" into starkit header.
info      Inserting TEApot metadata
info        Nothing to insert
info       
notice      Extending the list of provided packages
info       
info      F     0B   /home/vminasyan/workspace/tests/TclDevKit/empty.tcl
info       
info      Generated wrap
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't test, but I think you are missing the prefix argument

```
-prefix /TclDevKit/bin/base-tk-<whatever-your-platform>
```

so your command should be something like this:

```
/opt/TclDevKit-5.2/bin/tclapp -prefix /TclDevKit/bin/base-tk-<whatever-your-platform> -out wrap empty.tcl
```

Anyway I recommend you to use a project file. You can create it executing `tclapp` without any argument (note: you'll need a Graphic Enviorment)